# ¿Como puedo leer o descargar un pdf en react native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

Quiero poder visualizar o en su defecto descargar un pdf usando **react native**. Estuve probando la librería **react-native-pdf** pero me da error, creo que es porque me pide hacer `npm link` y este comando me ha presentado problemas, estoy utilizando **expo** para poder probar mi app.

Comment: Lamentablemente yo tuve el mismo problema y al final tuve que hacer detatch de Expo, te lo recomiendo pues en el futuro vas a tener el mismo problema con otras funcionalidades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si lo que deseas es visualizar un archivo pdf que **esté en internet** (no local), puedes usar un pequeño "hack" con google drive.

```
<WebView source={{ uri: 'https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=url/archiv.pdf' }} />
```

Aquí un ejemplo con expo:

[exposnack](https://snack.expo.io/@noroboto/pdf-in-a-webview)

Espero que a alguien le sirva de ayuda.

Referencia https://forums.expo.io/t/open-pdf-with-expo/1143/5

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres descargar un PDF desde un servicio X que tengas implementado puedes ocupar la libreria [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob), con esta libreria podrás incluso tener una Previsualización del documento que estas descargando. Saludos